# How to select 400 rows out of 50000 rows in excel randomly?

Tags: excel

I have excel file with 50000 rows,it can be divided into 90 categories, I want to select 400-500 random rows. But random rows should contain atleast 2 rows from each category.
Categories are stored in seperate column.

Is there any way to do that in excel?

Note: I tried with google and couldn't get results.

Help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the layout of your data. It seems like the categories in separate columns bit will make it harder.

Comment: I'm having 24 columns.First column have product names. I want to select atleast 2 rows for each product.Hope I'm clear.

Comment: That is clear, as far as it goes. But a picture of what your data looks like would help a lot.

Comment: I just removed the [macros] tag as it does not pertain to this post. I am not quite sure if you want to achieve this with formulas only or if you want to do this with VBA (due to the macros tag). If so, please add the [Excel-VBA] tag to you question. If you are aiming for a VBA solution then you might want to consider updating your post with the VBA code you have attempted to write thus far.

Comment: I want to do it without any macros.

Comment: "Is there any way to do that in excel?" <--- yes.. Sample data pls.. Coz I can't seem to get in which sheet does the "source" data is located.. + how does this ->> "Categories are stored in seperate column." look like.. || Without the info.. the solution will most likely suggested with assumptions of it. ( :